# build scripts that can create the WARs for my Talend jobs using Ant or Maven

Tags: ant, talend

I am trying to have a build scripts that can create the WARs for my Talend jobs using Ant or Maven based build scripts that can be run from command line and eventually be integrated into a continuous integration system like Hudson. There are ways to integrate Ant/Maven scripts in the Talend Enterprise edition 5.2.1 , however I am trying to achieve this using the community edition. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You can export jobs to WAR (or ZIP, or whatever you want) by using the command line export tool. Are you aware of this?

Comment: In order to be more complete, your answer could include a link to this page : http://www.talendforge.org/tutorials/tutorial.php?idTuto=48#s10

Comment: Thanks a lot Rogier and Jean. I have one more query to go, I read the Talend Administration Center can be configured with the Talend ESB studio, however I am using Talend open source ETL, so can I use the Administration Centre to add projects from my ETL studio? I am sorry this might be a silly question, I am a newbie to Talend.

Comment: I'd be interested in this too - it seems to me they deliberately make it so you have to manually export jobs in the open source version from TOS only.